# See exactly which service is using a file on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, services, resource-monitor, resource-usage

I've looked around a bit, but wasn't able to find what I was looking for :(
I want to know which **service** exactly is using a certain file. I know I can use *Resource Monitor* to see which process is using a file, but as we know in a single svchost.exe process there can be quite a few services residing.
Does anyone have any tips on getting to such information?

Answer (score 1):

You should give [Processor-Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) a try.

It's an extremely useful tool.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I think I'm missing something, because I can see which windows service is using the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only way is to use the built-in Resource Monitor (Win 7 and up), checking the CPU using services and hope the one that's using the HDD is also consuming some CPU and gives itself away :P